# Apache ProxyPass only for subdomain and folder

Tags: apache

I want to use ProxyPass and only apply for the following subdomain and folder:

de.domain.com/blog/ -> http://blog.olddomain.com/de/

Our new page will have multiple subdomains (each per locale). When i only use this:

```
ProxyPass /blog/ http://blog.olddomain.com/de/
ProxyPassReverse /blog/ http://blog.olddomain.com/de/
```

All subdomains are using the rule. So my question is, how can i tell ProxyPass only apply this on `de.domain.com/blog/` and not on `en.domain.com/blog/` etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using this in your `.htaccess` or in apache config files? Also, what is the apache version?

Comment: In apache config. Apache/2.4.28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option would be to split the VirtualHost configuration, and first have separate virtual host for `de.domain.com` which will include the above ProxyPass directives, and then have another virtual host for `*.domain.com`, without ProxyPass:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName de.example.com
  ProxyPass /blog/ http://blog.olddomain.com/de/ 
  ProxyPassReverse /blog/ http://blog.olddomain.com/de/ 
  # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName *.example.com 
  # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

If you don't want to do that (for example because it might make configuration maintenance more complicated) you can try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =de.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule /blog/(.*) http://blog.olddomain.com/de/$1 [NC,P,L]
ProxyPassReverse /blog/ http://blog.olddomain.com/de/
```

Comment: Thank you! So when i add this:

`<VirtualHost de.example.com:443>  
  ProxyPass /blog/ http://blog.olddomain.com/de/  
  ProxyPassReverse /blog/ http://blog.olddomain.com/de/  
</VirtualHost>`

This should work? I am using 433 because the page has SSL.

Or do i need to add another VirtualHost?

Comment: Thank you! I added your code, but it seems not compatible with the Bitnami Wordpress Multisite on AWS i used. When i add those. VirtualHost entries, the /blog/ URL is working ... but all the other URLs are not working anymore and i get a default Bitnami Welcome page.

Comment: This should not interfere with current setup, as long as you copy all existing configuration directives to both VirtualHosts, in place of `# Other directives here`

Comment: Your Rewrite solution saved my day !

Comment: Keep in mind that (for very high traffic), to second solution, with `[P]` flag, might have some performance impact