# resolve URL domain with external subdomain contents

Tags: apache, dns, hostname

I've purchased a new domain, lets call it example.ca.

I need the above URL to resolve in the browser, with the contents of another site, in this case www.test.ca/othersite

The expected behaviour is so when a user types example.ca, the site will load the contents of the www.test.ca/othersite, while still appearing the above URL as example.ca

I am not looking for a redirect, so wondering how this can be done using DNS and apache rules. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache ProxyPass only for subdomain and folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400572/apache-proxypass-only-for-subdomain-and-folder)

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is exactly the same, just replace `/blog/` with `/`